# Is the season pass shared between PSN accounts?

Tags: psn, destiny

My dad accidentally put money on his ps4 account, and I'm wondering if he buys the Destiny expansion pass will I get it on my ps4 account as well because we both share the same ps4. The reason why I'm asking is because when I bought a game on my account he also got it on his account as well. Thanks.

Comment: With Destiny + Season pass on my account, other people can access the content on my console. However it may now be possible to purchase the season pass on an account that doesn't own the game.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you activate the PS4 for the account that purchased the Expansion Pass then all other accounts on that PS4 should be able to access it's content.

From: https://www.bungie.net/en/Forum/Post/88233432/0/0